# Как сделать плиточную диаграмму?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать такую плиточную диаграмму, где цвет и высота плиток зависят от значений. Как можно реализовать такое?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaximLensky в идеале из json, но для наглядности хватит с примерными данными

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245173/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-js#comment2186075_1245173 - Дубликат? Интересно, откуда задача...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME , да, та же задача. Но почему то ответов таки не нашел(

Answer (score 5):

Вариант с [three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube) как раз вам предмет для изучения ... там где 3D это в самый раз ..

За геометрию куба отвечает вот такая строка: `new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,2,1);`

За освещение отвечает эта строка: `new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();`

Как создавать в цикле с правильным положением камеры и объектов я пока не знаю ...чем больше кубов тем больше кода в моём случае ...

Вот такая попытка показать 3D диаграму .... лично я дальше буду изучать так как мне понравилось ...

```html
<body style="height: 100vh; margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r126/three.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 2, 1);
    const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 3, 1);
    const geometry3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 5, 1);
    const geometry4 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material);
    const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material);
    const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry3, material);
    const cube3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry4, material);
    cube.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    cube1.position.set(2, 0.5, 0);
    cube2.position.set(4, 1.5, 0);
    cube3.position.set(5.6, -0.4, 0);
    scene.add(cube, cube1, cube2, cube3);
    camera.position.set(10, 1, 10);
    camera.rotation.set(0, 0.6, 0);
    
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      cube1.rotation.y += 0.01;
      cube2.rotation.y += 0.01;
      cube3.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

А в чём собственно возникают сложности? Нарисовать это можно на чистом CSS, смотрите пример ниже. А значения подставлять, например, через переменные с помощью скрипта, думаю, сами справитесь, ничего сложного в этом нет.

```css
.chart {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 10em;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.bar {
  transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-135deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 10em;
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(1em);
  background: #ffd988;
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-10em) translateZ(1em);
  background: #fecd5e;
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(21em);
  background: #ffe8af;
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(0em) translateZ(-13em) rotate(180deg);
  background: #ffe8af;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em rgb(0 0 0 / 30%), 0.6em -1em 3em rgb(0 0 0 / 30%), 1em 1em 10em rgb(254 254 254 / 80%);
}

.chart_m .left,
.chart_m .right {
  height: 2em;
}

.chart_m .left {
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateY(8em) translateZ(1em);
  background: #ededed;
}

.chart_m .right {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(6em) translateZ(1em);
  background: #e4e2e2;
}

.chart_m .top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-3em);
  background: #f3f2f2;
}

.chart_m .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(0em) translateZ(3em) rotate(180deg);
  background: #f3f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face top"></div>
    <div class="face bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chart chart_m">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face top"></div>
    <div class="face bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: С прямыми углами, да, просто. Но, когда красявости начинаешь добавлять (радиусы + градиенты)... уже полдня убил. Кстати, нижняя грань не нужна, её нет на рисунках.

Comment: а меня вот зацепило :) Думаю, если я могу сделать [так](https://codepen.io/UModeL/pen/mdrPOme), то и это не трудно. Чую, ошибся.

Comment: Привет Паша ! Проблема будет в интэрактивности .... там как минимум должен быть three + 3mf или gltf - в общем как то так

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/G5pm0h0/3d-v1.gif примерно вот такая штука в css будет на 200 +- строк - в three на 8, я сохранил как gif что бы показать

Comment: @Sevastopol' Большое спасибо за ответ, но остался еще один вопрос. Как эти детальки рядом друг друга ставить, ведь по макету работает как 3д модель немного в наклоне? Можете пожалуйста объяснить этот момент для полной наглядности?